# How to remove letters with preceding full stop using php regex?

Tags: php, regex

One of my script has the following function to return a float value from a text value consist with currency code.

```
function preformatFloat($value, $decimal_point = '.')
{
    if ($decimal_point != '.' && strpos($value, $decimal_point)) {
        $value = str_replace('.', '~', $value);
        $value = str_replace($decimal_point, '.', $value);
    }
    return (float)preg_replace('/[^0-9\-\.]/', '', $value);
}
```

And if I run this function

```
echo preformatFloat("Rs.990.00",".");
```

I got the answer as `0.99` but I wanted to get the value as `990.00`
I tried lot by modifying regex value but no luck.
Can you please help with this. Thank you

Comment: Your replacing leaves the value as `.990.00`, and when you parse that as a float, of course you get `.99`

Comment: @CBroe what should I do for it friend?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
function preformatFloat($string)
{
    $precedingFullStop = strpos($string, ".");
    $newString = substr($string, $precedingFullStop + 1);

    return (float)preg_replace('/[^0-9\-\.]/', '', $newString);
}
echo preformatFloat("PKR.200.09");
```

Comment: This works. Thanks. Is there any way of doing this with Regex?

Comment: try replacing with -> return (float)preg_replace('/[^0-9\-\.]/', '', $newString);

Comment: No it is not. I get the same old result.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a different approach using a RegExp match. It tries to find the first valid (float) number and ignores anything else.

```
function parseFloatInput(
    $value, 
    $decimal_separator = '.', 
    $thousand_separator = ','
) {
    $pattern = '(
       # define named templates for the separators, 
       # escape variable values for pattern
       (?(DEFINE)(?<dp>'.preg_quote($decimal_separator).'))
       (?(DEFINE)(?<tp>'.preg_quote($thousand_separator).'))
       (
         # at least one digit
         (?:\d+)
         # any repeat: a thousand separator followed by 3 digits
         (?:(?&tp)?\d{3})*
         # one or no:  decimal separator followed by at least one digit
         (?:(?&dp)?\d+)?
       )
    )x';
    if (preg_match($pattern, $value, $match)) {
        return (float)str_replace(
            [$thousand_separator, $decimal_separator], 
            ['', '.'], 
            $match[0]
        );
    }
    return NAN;
}

var_dump(parseFloatInput("Rs.990.99","."));
var_dump(parseFloatInput("Rs.1,990.99","."));
var_dump(parseFloatInput("Rs.990.99",","));
var_dump(parseFloatInput("Rs.",","));
```

Output:

```
float(990.99)
float(1990.99)
float(990)
float(NAN)
```

### Notes

1. `/` is not the only possible delimiter. Any non alpha numeric character works. But only parentheses/brackets do not conflict with usage inside the pattern. So I prefer using `()` - reading it as group 0.
2. Modifier `x` for extended syntax. It allows to format and comment the pattern.
3. The separators are defined as templates, to improve the readability of the actual matching part.